# filter link text to have the http

Tags: php

I've got a script that will cherry pick urls that people have inserted into content.

It's meant to auto link them but the link doesn't when the "http://" is omitted. What is a smart way, with possibly one line of code that I can add it back (if it isn't there)

using LAMP

`(strpos($edm['link'], 'http://')!==false)?$edm['link']:'http://'.$edm['link']`
is what i tried

Comment: It'd be better if you [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5933181/edit) that into your question.

Comment: I was talking about your comment left on your own question.

Comment: @alex Ah fair enough. I take that back then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$prefix = 'http://';

if (strpos($url, $prefix) !== 0) {
    $url = $prefix . $url; 
}
```

Also, your example...

```
(strpos($edm['link'], 'http://')!==false) ? $edm['link'] : 'http://'.$edm['link'];
```

...will fail on a matched URL such as...

```
facebook.com/l.php?u=http://example.com
```

...which will leave it as...

```
facebook.com/l.php?u=http://example.com
```

...which is probably not what you want. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Z1aK6).

However, [mine](http://ideone.com/oQrGE) doesn't have that problem :)

Comment: -1 I already have the script to cherry pick urls, that's no problem

Comment: @Jason OK, so was a downvote necessary for a misunderstanding? I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jason You downvote the first person to answer you? That seems logical...

Comment: @Jason your reasoning is stupid.

Comment: but i removed my down vote after you change the question.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way: first you delete the 'http://' part just in case it's already there, and then append it anyway.

```
edm['link'] = "http://" . preg_replace('#^http://#','',edm['link']);
```

Note: This won't work for https, but it's easy to do.

Comment: Is it easy? Change the code so it accept http, https and ftp.